# Please, don't game the system!

Tags: discussion, notifications, etiquette

Few minutes after the votes have been refilled at 00:00 UTC all unanswered questions with at least 1 answer got up vote on that answer.

I'm not sure if this is a coincidence or a deliberated action attempting to site gets a good ratio of answered questions.

It's clear to me that we have a strong community here and we can achieve SE goals organically.

Avoid any attempt to game the system.

Comment: "after the votes were reloaded?" I'm confused.  What happened?

Comment: It's more fun to dig old games out of your garage and answer the unanswered questions :)

Comment: @lilserf He probably means when the daily vote limit reset at 00:00 UTC (we get 30 votes per day)

Comment: @lilserf: Edited to better understanding. Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, there were two blog posts recently that strongly encouraged people to vote more often ([When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) and [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)), because most betas have the exact opposite problem -- people don't vote nearly enough. People also have the [Suffrage badge](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/57/suffrage) to tempt them. It's possible people are gaming the badge by just mass upvoting questions, but if so hopefully that was a one time thing now that they've got the badge

Comment: In this case I think it was just to sweep the unanswered questions. Use all 30 votes/day is a good thing but throw them on any random question, it's not.